# How to display numbers on the left side and on the bottom of my 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to print a 2 dimensions array with some numbers on the left side and on the bottom.
Here is my code for the initialization, wich is in the class Grille :

```
class Grille {

String[][] grille = new String[7][8];

public Grille() { 
    for (int line = 0; line < grille.length; line++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < grille[column].length; column++) {
            grille[line][column] = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I print my array with this, in the same class Grille:

```
  public void print() {
    for (int line = 0; line < grille.length; line++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < grille[line].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(grille[line][column] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }



}
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

there are spaces between numbers in horizontal lines to make the difference and to know that they arre not in the same column

thank you!!

Comment: learn the difference between System.out.println and System.out.print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is fairly straight-forward. If you have a Two-Dimensional array, print `array[I][0]` until you reach `array.length`.

Then starting at `J = 0`, print `array[I][J]` until you reach `array[i].length`. Where I is the index of the last row.

The following code will print:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[][] = 
    {
        {6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    };

    int array2[][] =
    {
        {6},
        {5},
        {4},
        {3},
        {2},
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    };

    print(array);
    System.out.println("\n");
    print(array2);
}

public static void print(int[][] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (i == array.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(array[i][0] + "\n ");
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; ++j) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println(array[i][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       boolean b=true;
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
             for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
             {
                if(i==array.length-1)
                {
                                if(b)
                                   {
                                     System.out.print(array[i][0]+"\n");
                                     b=false;
                                    }

                System.out.print(" "+array[i][j]);
                }
             else
                {
                 System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                 break;
                }
              }
            System.out.print("\n");
       }
```